# Save and Load current frame in Actionscript 3 (Adobe Flash AIR)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, save, load

I have an interactive flash application Actionscript 3 to be deployed in Android device (thru Adobe Air). There will be a Save button (btnSave) that will save current progress of a user eventhough he closes the app or another will use it. There's also a Load button (btnLoad) to load the progress of the user. This is my code and I can't make it work. Thanks!

```
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(“save”);

btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveCurrentFrame);

function saveCurrentFrame(event:MouseEvent):void

{
mySharedObject.data.lastframe= this.currentFrame;
mySharedObject.flush();
}

btnLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getLastFrame);

function getLastFrame():int

{
return mySharedObject.data.lastframe;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the errors being faced? Are there any errors? Have you tried debugging with `trace` statements?

Comment: there's a syntax error sir.

Comment: Move your code off timeline, should do.

Comment: @Vesper What do you mean move my code off the timeline? Thank you

Comment: Mmm. Your `getLastFrame()` is not a valid listener. You should instead make a listener that reads from that function and does whatever suitable with that data. `btnLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadFrame); function loadFrame(event:MouseEvent):void { gotoAndStop(getLastFrame()); }` for example.

Comment: @Vesper, it's still syntax error. :(

Comment: @this is my code now: var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(“save”);

btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveCurrentFrame);

function saveCurrentFrame(event:MouseEvent):void

{
mySharedObject.data.lastframe= this.currentFrame;
mySharedObject.flush();
}

btnLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadFrame); 
function loadFrame(event:MouseEvent):void { 
gotoAndStop(getLastFrame()); 
}

Answer (score 1):

You need not only to read the saved last frame, but to move the playhead to it as well.

```
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("save");

btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveCurrentFrame);
btnLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getLastFrame);

function saveCurrentFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    mySharedObject.data.lastframe = currentFrame;
    mySharedObject.flush();
}

function getLastFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (mySharedObject.data.lastframe != null)
    {
        gotoAndStop(mySharedObject.data.lastframe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when I close my app and reopen it, the app opens the welcome splash screen, not to the scene where it was saved. What could be the error? Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't advise to use scenes at all. Make it a MovieClip that is available by the time splash screen shows.